# What could be causing the category to be appearing as the post title in the title tag?

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, wp-title

As the title of the questions states, I have this site where in the title tags, the category is appearing as the post title, which is killing my client's SEO, of course. I've disabled all plugins that could remotely be affecting it, picked through the files, rebuilt and cleaned up the header.php file, and everything else I could think of. And nothing.

The site is http://vibrantnation.com. And if you look at a blog post, and inspect the source code, you'll see what I mean in the  tag. It's over-writing Yoast's SEO plugin and what's in there as well.

Anyone have any suggestions for how I can tell where that title tag is being pulled from, or what's changing the post titles to be a category, and then WP is picking up the category and treating it like a post title.

The title that's appearing is  blog . "Blog" is something that I haven't figured out exactly where it's coming from either.

I think it has something to do with how the theme was coded(I inherited this mess, which is why I don't know what's what) to display the breadcrumbs in the grey bar across the screen.

Comment: It's probably to do with the defaults or fallback in yoast seo settings, at a cursory guess.

Comment: I've disabled that plugin, taken a look, and still get the same behavior.

Comment: Try checking your Permalink settings... change them and then change them back.

Comment: Nope. Still showing up. I'm going through this theme file by file, and trying to see what/where the breadcrumbs are being generated from. I think that may have something to do with it. This thing has 3 functions files.

Comment: If you change the permalinks to something different is it still enforced? If so it may be the theme. Try switching theme to another (preferably the wordpress 201x theme you have). If that works it's more than likely your theme.

Comment: I'm certain it's the theme. I'm combing through all the code trying to find what's responsible. It's a child theme of a parent theme bought off Themeforest, and the code is totally jacked up. The last developer left everything like a ball of tangled-up Christmas lights.

Comment: Many feels friend. Been there, done that. My thoughts are with you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this theme so what I'm about to say is a wild guess and you've probably alright tried it but the breadcrumbs could be coming from anywhere it all depends how many files are in the theme.

If the theme has a single.php check there for the breadcrumbs. Check the index.php or anything else that makes the blog post display the content inside. I can't really help other than that cause I don't know what file the theme has.

Good luck my friend

Comment: The theme is "Wild Community" which they bought off Themeforest, and then had another guy build on it, and when that began to get out of his control, they gave it to me. Familiar story.

I've looked in those files and couldn't see anything, because that makes the most sense, but I'll look again. That was pretty late at night and I was fading. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, thinking about it if you look in the single.php page if the code in there is short and it's doing something like get_template_part('blog-content', get_post_format()); then I would suggest to look inside the blog-content.php as you can see the single is fetching it's content from the blog-content template so all the content displayed on the single blog page should be in the blog-content. Obviously yours probably won't be called blog-content the same principle applies.